# DeviceTree Overlay fails

Tags: device-tree

Following setup here: 
TinkerBoard-S with rk3288 Chip running armbian with legacy Kernel 4.4.199

Now I would like to add an overlay to the existing one. Here is how the existing one looks like:

```
 dsi@ff960000 {
                reg = <0x0 0xff960000 0x0 0x4000>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x13 0x4>;
                compatible = "rockchip,rk3288-mipi-dsi", "snps,dw-mipi-dsi";
                clock-names = "ref", "pclk";
                reset-names = "apb";
                clocks = <0x7 0x7e 0x7 0x164>;
                power-domains = <0x72 0x9>;
                resets = <0x7 0x73>;
                status = "okay";
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                phandle = <0xe9>;
                #size-cells = <0x0>;
                rockchip,grf = <0x47>;

                ports {
                        #address-cells = <0x1>;
                        #size-cells = <0x0>;

                        port {
                                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                                phandle = <0xea>;
                                #size-cells = <0x0>;

                                endpoint@0 {
                                        reg = <0x0>;
                                        remote-endpoint = <0x89>;
                                        phandle = <0x81>;
                                };

                                endpoint@1 {
                                        reg = <0x1>;
                                        remote-endpoint = <0x8a>;
                                        phandle = <0x86>;
                                };
                        };
                };

                mipi-panel {
                        reg = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "asus,tc358762";
                        status = "okay";
                        phandle = <0xeb>;
                };
        };

dsi@ff964000 {
                reg = <0x0 0xff964000 0x0 0x4000>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x14 0x4>;
                compatible = "rockchip,rk3288-mipi-dsi", "snps,dw-mipi-dsi";
                clock-names = "ref", "pclk";
                reset-names = "apb";
                clocks = <0x7 0x7e 0x7 0x165>;
                power-domains = <0x72 0x9>;
                resets = <0x7 0x74>;
                status = "disabled";
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                phandle = <0xec>;
                #size-cells = <0x0>;
                rockchip,grf = <0x47>;

                ports {
                        #address-cells = <0x1>;
                        #size-cells = <0x0>;

                        port {
                                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                                phandle = <0xed>;
                                #size-cells = <0x0>;

                                endpoint@0 {
                                        reg = <0x0>;
                                        remote-endpoint = <0x8b>;
                                        phandle = <0x83>;
 };

                                endpoint@1 {
                                        reg = <0x1>;
                                        remote-endpoint = <0x8c>;
                                        phandle = <0x88>;
                                };
                        };
                };
        };


....

 aliases {
                i2c0 = "/i2c@ff650000";
                i2c1 = "/i2c@ff140000";
                i2c2 = "/i2c@ff660000";
                i2c3 = "/i2c@ff150000";
                i2c4 = "/i2c@ff160000";
                i2c5 = "/i2c@ff170000";
                dsi0 = "/dsi@ff960000";
                dsi1 = "/dsi@ff964000";
                spi0 = "/spi@ff110000";
                spi1 = "/spi@ff120000";
                spi2 = "/spi@ff130000";
                mshc0 = "/dwmmc@ff0f0000";
                mshc1 = "/dwmmc@ff0c0000";
                mshc2 = "/dwmmc@ff0d0000";
                mshc3 = "/dwmmc@ff0e0000";
                serial0 = "/serial@ff180000";
                serial1 = "/serial@ff190000";
                serial2 = "/serial@ff690000";
                serial3 = "/serial@ff1b0000";
                serial4 = "/serial@ff1c0000";
                testcase-alias = "/testcase-data";
                ethernet0 = "/ethernet@ff290000";
        };
```

Now I would like to attach a different panel to dsi0. 
Therefore I have created and compiled the following overlay:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "rockchip,rk3288-miniarm", "rockchip,rk3288";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&dsi0> ;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            dsi_panel:panel 
            {
                compatible = "simple-panel-dsi";
                reg = <0> ;
                //backlight = < & backlight > ;
                //dsi,flags = <(MIPI_DSI_MODE_VIDEO | MIPI_DSI_MODE_VIDEO_BURST)>;
                //dsi,format = <MIPI_DSI_FMT_RGB888>;
                //bus-format = <MEDIA_BUS_FMT_RGB666_1X18>;
                dsi,lanes = <2> ;
                status = "okay";
                panel-init-sequence = [
                    05 20 01 29
                    05 96 01 11
                ];
                panel-exit-sequence = [
                    05 05 01 28
                    05 78 01 10
                ];
                disp_timings: display-timings 
                {
                    native-mode = <&timing0> ;
                    timing0:timing0 
                    {
                        clock-frequency = <64000000> ;
                        hactive = <768> ;
                        vactive = <1024> ;
                        hsync-len = <5> ; //20, 50
                        hback-porch = <25> ; //50, 56
                        hfront-porch = <150> ; //50, 30
                        vsync-len = <1> ;
                        vback-porch = <15> ;
                        vfront-porch = <100> ;
                        hsync-active = <0> ;
                        vsync-active = <0> ;
                        de-active = <0> ;
                        pixelclk-active = <0> ;
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };

};
```

When I am starting the board then I get these errors:

```
[    0.000000] L2C: failed to init: -19
[    0.000000] rockchip_clk_register_branches: unknown clock type 9
[    1.506512] vcc_sd: regulator get failed, ret=-517
[    1.506917] vcc_flash: regulator get failed, ret=-517
[    2.185904] rk-vcodec ff9a0000.vpu-service: no regulator for vcodec
[    2.187620] rk-vcodec ff9a0000.vpu-service: could not find power_model node
[    2.188089] rk-vcodec ff9c0000.hevc-service: no regulator for vcodec
[    2.189531] rk-vcodec ff9c0000.hevc-service: could not find power_model node
[    2.276168] rockchip-spi ff130000.spi: no high_speed pinctrl state
[    2.288235] rk_gmac-dwmac ff290000.ethernet: phy regulator is not available yet, deferred probing
[    2.300406] Rockchip WiFi SYS interface (V1.00) ...
[    2.307694] ff540000.usb supply vusb_d not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.315123] ff540000.usb supply vusb_a not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.436886] ff580000.usb supply vusb_d not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.444329] ff580000.usb supply vusb_a not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.451950] dwc2 ff580000.usb: dwc2_core_reset() HANG! Soft Reset GRSTCTL=80000001
[    2.571761] dwc2 ff580000.usb: dwc2_wait_for_mode: Couldn't set device mode
[    2.849156] tinker-mcu: send_cmds: send command failed, ret = -6
[    2.855855] tinker-mcu: tinker_mcu_probe: init_cmd_check failed, -6
[    2.872950] rockchip-sy-mipi-dphy ff770000.syscon:mipi-phy-rx0: invalid resource
[    2.885551] rk_tsadcv2_temp_to_code: Invalid conversion table: code=4095, temperature=2147483647
[    2.911600] rockchip_cpuclk_pre_rate_change: Invalid rate : 500000000 for cpuclk
[    2.993716] ff960000.dsi.0 supply power not found, using dummy regulator
[    3.001247] dw-mipi-dsi ff960000.dsi: device mode is unsupported
[    3.007974] panel-simple-dsi: probe of ff960000.dsi.0 failed with error -22
[    3.015736] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    3.020867] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1 at fs/sysfs/dir.c:31 sysfs_warn_dup+0x78/0x88()
[    3.029247] sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/platform/ff960000.dsi/ff960000.dsi.0'
[    3.039257] Modules linked in:
[    3.042640] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.4.199-rockchip #37
[    3.050238] Hardware name: Rockchip (Device Tree)
[    3.055453] [<c011126c>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c010cb54>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[    3.064033] [<c010cb54>] (show_stack) from [<c06298fc>] (dump_stack+0x90/0xa4)
[    3.072035] [<c06298fc>] (dump_stack) from [<c01207f4>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x94/0xc4)
[    3.080995] [<c01207f4>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c0120864>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x40/0x48)
[    3.090628] [<c0120864>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<c02df158>] (sysfs_warn_dup+0x78/0x88)
[    3.099685] [<c02df158>] (sysfs_warn_dup) from [<c02df250>] (sysfs_create_dir_ns+0x94/0xa0)
[    3.108935] [<c02df250>] (sysfs_create_dir_ns) from [<c062c328>] (kobject_add_internal+0xa4/0x2d4)
[    3.118856] [<c062c328>] (kobject_add_internal) from [<c062c5ac>] (kobject_add+0x54/0x9c)
[    3.127914] [<c062c5ac>] (kobject_add) from [<c0758744>] (device_add+0x100/0x5b0)
[    3.136203] [<c0758744>] (device_add) from [<c0726cb0>] (mipi_dsi_host_register+0x100/0x1dc)
[    3.145550] [<c0726cb0>] (mipi_dsi_host_register) from [<c0a331dc>] (dw_mipi_dsi_probe+0x80/0xc8)
[    3.155376] [<c0a331dc>] (dw_mipi_dsi_probe) from [<c075d740>] (platform_drv_probe+0x60/0xbc)
[    3.164817] [<c075d740>] (platform_drv_probe) from [<c075b938>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f4/0x2e8)
[    3.174644] [<c075b938>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c075bac0>] (__driver_attach+0x94/0x98)
[    3.183987] [<c075bac0>] (__driver_attach) from [<c0759a08>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x5c/0xac)
[    3.193044] [<c0759a08>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<c075b1d0>] (driver_attach+0x2c/0x30)
[    3.201908] [<c075b1d0>] (driver_attach) from [<c075adc4>] (bus_add_driver+0x19c/0x220)
[    3.210771] [<c075adc4>] (bus_add_driver) from [<c075c514>] (driver_register+0x88/0x104)
[    3.219729] [<c075c514>] (driver_register) from [<c075d688>] (__platform_driver_register+0x50/0x58)
[    3.229747] [<c075d688>] (__platform_driver_register) from [<c124bd3c>] (dw_mipi_dsi_driver_init+0x1c/0x20)
[    3.240535] [<c124bd3c>] (dw_mipi_dsi_driver_init) from [<c0101b0c>] (do_one_initcall+0xa0/0x1f0)
[    3.250362] [<c0101b0c>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c1200fbc>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x1e8/0x28c)
[    3.259997] [<c1200fbc>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c0d3eb98>] (kernel_init+0x18/0x118)
[    3.269152] [<c0d3eb98>] (kernel_init) from [<c0108110>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x24)
[    3.277578] ---[ end trace 8535bac3d55643c8 ]---
[    3.282712] kobject_add_internal failed for ff960000.dsi.0 with -EEXIST, don't try to register things with the same name in the same directory.
[    3.296969] dw-mipi-dsi ff960000.dsi: failed to add DSI device /dsi@ff960000/mipi-panel: -17
[    3.308501] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: failed to bind ff960000.dsi (ops 0xc0ec512c): -517
[    3.756271] usb 3-1: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 255 but max is 6
[    3.764558] usb 3-1: config 1 has no interface number 6
[    3.882013] tinker-ft5406: tinker_ft5406_probe: wait connected timeout
[    3.889355] [board_info] create Board_info_proc_file sucessed!
[    3.895958] project_id_2:0x0, project_id_1:0x0, project_id_0:0x0
[    3.902782] ram_id_2:0x0, ram_id_1:0x1, ram_id_0:0x0
[    3.908443] pcb_id_2:0x0, pcb_id_1:0x1, pcb_id_0:0x0
[    6.079881] rk_gmac-dwmac ff290000.ethernet: cannot get clock clk_mac_speed
[    6.199189] ff960000.dsi.0 supply power not found, using dummy regulator
[    6.210087] dw-mipi-dsi ff960000.dsi: device mode is unsupported
[    6.216907] panel-simple-dsi: probe of ff960000.dsi.0 failed with error -22
[    6.224765] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    6.229957] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 102 at fs/sysfs/dir.c:31 sysfs_warn_dup+0x78/0x88()
[    6.238598] sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/platform/ff960000.dsi/ff960000.dsi.0'
[    6.248675] Modules linked in:
[    6.252113] CPU: 1 PID: 102 Comm: kworker/u8:1 Tainted: G        W       4.4.199-rockchip #37
[    6.261588] Hardware name: Rockchip (Device Tree)
[    6.266828] Workqueue: deferwq deferred_probe_work_func
[    6.272654] [<c011126c>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c010cb54>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[    6.281279] [<c010cb54>] (show_stack) from [<c06298fc>] (dump_stack+0x90/0xa4)
[    6.289326] [<c06298fc>] (dump_stack) from [<c01207f4>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x94/0xc4)
[    6.298332] [<c01207f4>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c0120864>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x40/0x48)
[    6.308014] [<c0120864>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<c02df158>] (sysfs_warn_dup+0x78/0x88)
[    6.317119] [<c02df158>] (sysfs_warn_dup) from [<c02df250>] (sysfs_create_dir_ns+0x94/0xa0)
[    6.326401] [<c02df250>] (sysfs_create_dir_ns) from [<c062c328>] (kobject_add_internal+0xa4/0x2d4)
[    6.336315] [<c062c328>] (kobject_add_internal) from [<c062c5ac>] (kobject_add+0x54/0x9c)
[    6.345364] [<c062c5ac>] (kobject_add) from [<c0758744>] (device_add+0x100/0x5b0)
[    6.353646] [<c0758744>] (device_add) from [<c0726cb0>] (mipi_dsi_host_register+0x100/0x1dc)
[    6.362985] [<c0726cb0>] (mipi_dsi_host_register) from [<c0a331dc>] (dw_mipi_dsi_probe+0x80/0xc8)
[    6.372802] [<c0a331dc>] (dw_mipi_dsi_probe) from [<c075d740>] (platform_drv_probe+0x60/0xbc)
[    6.382236] [<c075d740>] (platform_drv_probe) from [<c075b938>] (driver_probe_device+0x1f4/0x2e8)
[    6.392055] [<c075b938>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c075bb7c>] (__device_attach_driver+0xb8/0xc4)
[    6.402065] [<c075bb7c>] (__device_attach_driver) from [<c0759ad8>] (bus_for_each_drv+0x54/0xa4)
[    6.411786] [<c0759ad8>] (bus_for_each_drv) from [<c075b668>] (__device_attach+0x9c/0x124)
[    6.420929] [<c075b668>] (__device_attach) from [<c075bbe4>] (device_initial_probe+0x1c/0x20)
[    6.430357] [<c075bbe4>] (device_initial_probe) from [<c075ab00>] (bus_probe_device+0x94/0x9c)
[    6.439883] [<c075ab00>] (bus_probe_device) from [<c075af6c>] (deferred_probe_work_func+0x74/0xa0)
[    6.449794] [<c075af6c>] (deferred_probe_work_func) from [<c0139d00>] (process_one_work+0x1f8/0x508)
[    6.459895] [<c0139d00>] (process_one_work) from [<c013ad64>] (worker_thread+0x68/0x558)
[    6.468845] [<c013ad64>] (worker_thread) from [<c01403f0>] (kthread+0x118/0x120)
[    6.477027] [<c01403f0>] (kthread) from [<c0108110>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x24)
```

Could it be, that this single error:

```
[    3.001247] dw-mipi-dsi ff960000.dsi: device mode is unsupported
[    3.007974] panel-simple-dsi: probe of ff960000.dsi.0 failed with error -22
```

Is the source of all the problems?

Cause after that error it looks like that it begins to repeat the messages...
Could somebody give me some hints or feedback about what could be wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the port 0 is Input node i.e. should be receiving data from video processor vopb or vopl, where as port 1 is for outpu i.e. for dsi display panel.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind expanding your answer a little and include (a) an explanation on where you think the OP made in error in the configuration, and (b) suggestions on how to solve the problem?